# What does the warning about missing firmware mean and how to fix it?

Tags: kernel

I did a fresh Ubuntu 13.04 x64 install. Right after that, I downloaded and installed the kernel 3.11.3-031103-generic which is running right now. One thing that concerns me is this message:

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8411-2.fw for module r8169
```

It's there from the begining! right after installing the kernel. Every now and then, when doing a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, there goes the message.

What exactly does that mean? And, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: someone just said to me that "if your wifi and ethernet are working, then you can ignore it". is it true?

Comment: That was my experience for a few years of using a debian laptop and seeing the missing firmware message. Though it's kinda annoying and I wish there was a way to suppress that particular message :P

Answer (score 3):

It means that those modules for the kernel you just installed have not been built. Unless you have a realtek network interface card you don't have to worry about those modules.

However if you want to install the realtek firmware because you do have a realtek card or even just to get rid of those error messages install a package called firmware-realtek.

Comment: thanks for your reply. is there a repository or something i need to add? E: Unable to locate package firmware-realtek

Comment: @Fred: I believe `firmware-realtek` is a Debian package, on Ubuntu it should be `linux-firmware`